# Making a panel persist despite click on page opened in browser

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I want to achieve this

1. Anchor a panel to a widget
2. make it persist
3. It will only appear or disappear when widget is clicked
4. or It may be made to disappear by clicking some button on it
   I want to achieve this because my addon is entirely residing in a panel 
   [Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=gradientoo&appver=10.0.1&platform=windows) is the addon.

Comment: The current Panel module included with the SDK will not persist when the user clicks back into the content document - this is an intentional design limitation.

What is the workflow you are trying to achieve? You mention ColorZilla - do you want users to be able to pick a color using that and then add it to the gradiant?3

Comment: I want users to click an element on the page to render gradient effect on it. The gradient effect will be generated by the generator in the panel. I want the panel to persist while the element is rendered gradient.

Comment: As I said, the Panel is limited - it is hard-wired to disappear when you click in the document. Just guessing, I wonder if you could do something with showing your Gradiant UI in an iframe injected into the content? It might give you more control?

Comment: well I always wanted to show it up as a draggable widget on the page content. However, I failed to do so as I could only load html and JS into the page via addon API (couldnt load css). Iframe is a great idea. Would my addon be accepted in review if I use this approach. Any examples of this approach in addon builder ?

Comment: Not currently, this was just a suggestion I had, and also makes the implementation much more as just web hacking ( which is easier? ) and less add-on hacking.

Comment: I tried to implement iframe and succeeded in injecting an iframe but failed to load content into it as I couldnt figure out what address should I write in "scr". I dont want to use a remote host for loading content in iframe as Mozilla will probably reject this approach. I want to use local files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I looked at this a bit more, and I'd like to apologize for a couple of things:

1. iframe won't work due to cross-domain security issues. That was a dead end.
2. I took waaay too long to get back to you, I've been on holiday and the place we were staying at only allowed 30 minutes of wifi per day, per room.

One way to approach this is to load your html directly from the data folder, pass it into the content script and inject it into the page. Something like this:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1043886/latest/

Some usability guidelines for this:

1. the user should be able to easily and obviously remove the injected content from the page. If you need to preserve the state of the injected content, you'll need to store that before removing the DOM nodes.
2. the injection should probably only happen when the user makes an action, eg by clicking on a widget. This should at least be the default.
3. there should be very careful handling of any data that gets sent back to the main.js add-on code from the injected content, as per usual. DO NOT TRUST DATA FROM THE WEB!

Comment: can I make this iframe draggable ? and please also review your answer in the light of latest addon sdk features. The API has been improved.

Answer (score 0):

You mean "noautohide" panel property?

It seems you cannot access to Panel object using the addon SDK, so you can create your own XUL Panel to set noautohide=true.

Comment: Yes, noautohide is an option. However, my UI is already developed in HTML and CSS. I would like to just re use that code. Using XUL panel would require lot of changes in my code. I fear some libraries like spectrum colorpicker and jquery will not work inside XUL panel.