# faster communication mechanism than "port" while communicating between addonScript and contentScript

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox addon named gradientoo. I use a colorpicker that generates color values which change the colors of an element on the page.To achieve this, addonScript and contentScript communicate with each other using "port". I have experienced that there is a lag between the color values changing on colorpicker and the values that reach page element. Is there a faster way to communicate to a page content from addon. Iframe is an idea as idscussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328471/making-a-panel-persist-despite-click-on-page-opened-in-browser). However , even an Iframe like this would need to use "port". Any ideas about a faster communication mechanism with high data transfer rate?

Comment: Why would the iframe need to use port? Can't you use window.postMessage ?

Comment: is window.postMessage faster? I worked a lot on transporting a JSON from html file to the addonScript using windows.postMessage but somehow faced lot of problem in parsing the data received in addonScript. Finally I changed my approach and used "port" which seems to have a slow data communication rate. Can some one show a working example of iframe communicating with page content using windows.postMessage.